# Foci cost in Shadowrun 5ed

Tags: magic-items, shadowrun-sr5

What is the cost of foci in Shadowrun 5ed?

In core rulebook p. 318 there is a table of Binding Cost in Karma - you have to synchronize the item to your astral signature.

On page 326 there is a table with cost in nuyen.

Does it mean that when I want to have the focus I have to pay both nuyen cost (item cost) and karma cost (binding cost)?

Comment: Suggest removing the shadowrun tag unless you intend for this question to be about the series as a whole and not just SR5, in which case, suggest removing the SR5 tag :D from your wording, I'm guessing you just mean SR5 specifically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Karma cost is mandatory.  The nuyen cost can be circumvented;  make your own, steal one, possibly take one off a dead mage?  I can't remember if a bound foci can be bound to a new owner if the old one is dead off-hand.  The nuyen cost can also be much higher than listed; if you're in a city where magic use is more heavily regulated (or, technically, the regulations are more strictly and reliably enforced) foci might be much harder to get without a Corporate SIN and a license to sling mojo.

Comment: You can rebind a foci to yourself, but you have to first break the bond that it had with the person before it.  I don't remember if the bond is still there after death, but either way, you have to make an Enchanting roll to unbind a foci.  Then, you have to rebind it with the normal costs and rolls.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to buy it with nuyen, and bind it with karma.

Just like with cyberware, you have to pay the nuyen cost *and* the Essence cost.